# mx:RadioButtonGroup gives selection null.. why?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have radiobutton group when i add a radiobutton, event then its selection is null, i debugged it and got that in mx:RadioButtonGroup , numRadioButtons is 0.. why is that? and how i can i set its selection.

```
public function AddRadioButton(elxRdButton:RadioButton):void
            {
                elxRdButton.group = id_RdGroup;
                elxRdButton.groupName = "id_RdGroup";
                if (elxRdButton.selected)
                {
                    id_RdGroup.selection = elxRdButton;
                    id_RdGroup.selectedValue = elxRdButton.value;
                }
                trace(id_RdGroup.selectedValue); // gives null
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="id_RdGroup"
                         change="id_RdGroup_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: I looks like you have a RadioButtonGroup, but no RadioButtons

Comment: RadioButton are added by calling AddRadioButton(RadioButton );

Answer (score 0):

use the namespace mx_internal, and add radiobutton like this

```
 use namespace mx_internal;

 public function AddRadioButton(elxRdButton:ElxRadioButton):void
    {
     id_RdGroup.addInstance(elxRdButton);
    if (elxRdButton.selected)
    {
    id_RdGroup.selection = elxRdButton;
    }
    m_aRdButtons.addItem(elxRdButton);
    }
```

Now selection will work perfectly :)